# Is there a Xamarin vs Visual Studio version matrix?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Cross posted here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/764356/xamarin-vs-visual-studio-version-matrix.html

Is there a handy reference showing which versions of Xamarin ship with which versions of VS?

​I did a fair bit of Googling and came up empty.

I would love to see something like:

VS Verion | Xamarin.iOS | Xamarin.Android

15.x.x | x.x.x | y.y.y

15.x.x | x.x.x | y.y.y

15.x.x | x.x.x | y.y.y

16.x.x | x.x.x | y.y.y

16.x.x | x.x.x | y.y.y

16.x.x | x.x.x | y.y.y

etc.

A few months back I spent days trying to figure out how and where which versions of Xamarin.iOS shipped with a specific version of VS.  Now I find myself asking the same question for a newer (but still not the most current) version of VS.

Cfg mgmt is very important and MS seems to get that.  You guys do a great job documenting things. Those of us that deal in highly regulated industries have a keen sense of appreciation for your documentation.  Having ready access to the table contemplated above would be phenomenal.  Maybe it exists but it is just not indexed high enough by the Google to be findable.  If so please reply with a link.  Maybe it doesn't exist and some kind soul from MS or the interwebs could find in in their hearts to create such a useful table.

Comment: You can check the release notes of Visual Studio from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes . It will contains the update log about the xamarin .

Comment: I’ve scoured the VS release notes and can’t find the detailed mapping I’m looking for. At best it says: VS xx supports Xamarin Y. I need VS xx.x.x ships with Xamarin.ios xx.x.x.x

Comment: I'm afraid that there is not such an API or interface  .

Answer (score 0):

Nope there isn't one. But you should create it!

Post it here, and on Twitter for some swagbucks. It would be really helpful!

Comment: As Xamarin versions shipped independently from VS, I would argue that such a matrix is not very helpful.

Comment: A definitive answer on this would be helpful. My understanding is that Xamarin forms is a Nugent you can manage independently but that Xamarin.ios and Xamarin.Android ship with VS.

Answer (score 0):

| 16.3.10 | 13.6.0.12 (e3c2b40) | 10.0.6.2 (d16-3/c407838) |

Comment: Please add some text that describes how this answers the OP's question.